# Is it possible to find out what the lower badge levels are, of a badge that you own?

Tags: steam-trading-cards

Is it possible to find out what the lower badge levels are, of a Trading Card Badge that you own?

I have Level 3, but I want to know what Levels 2 and 1 were, since I forgot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, but not through Steam itself.**

You can visit [**Steam Card Exchange**](https://www.steamcardexchange.net/) and search for the title of the badge.
Even though the search bar says "*Choose your game...*", it also works for Steam badges (like Steam Awards).